# How to find list index of a string containing a substring

Tags: python

```
ar = ['hello there','everyone']
```

How do I find the index of the element containing the substring "hell"?

Comment: You can use `enumerate` and `in` operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `next` with `enumerate`.

```
>>> next((i for i, v in enumerate(ar) if 'hell' in v), None)
0
>>>
```

Or filter:

```
>>> next(filter(lambda x: 'hell' in x[1], enumerate(ar)), [None])[0]
0
>>>
```

Or simply:

```
>>> ar.index(next(filter(lambda x: 'hell' in x, ar), None))
0
>>>
```

And:

```
>>> ar.index(next((v for v in ar if 'hell' in v), None))
0
>>>
```

Notice that all 4 solutions I added a `None` at the end (one case `[None]`). If you're sure that there will be matches in the list for sure, you could remove them.

Comment: In your first solution may be you can supply `-1` as default value. Otherwise it will rise `StopIteration` if the condition is not met!

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Done